# Is it possible to have a ListView in which the item id is the same as the id from the remote database?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I need to fetch some database entries from a remote server and display them in a listview. When the user clicks an item, another query should be sent to the database based on the item id (the original entry id from the remote database).

Is it possible to use an ArrayAdapter in which the item id (from onItemClick) is the same id from the database? If not, what would be the best approach to accomplish this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: onItemClick() you are getting some id which you can use to find the item from the list and after getting the item you can use item's id.

Comment: yes you may use ,you can set any view id an item using setId()

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
place item id in array and by using item click listener you will get position.

like     
private CharSequence Titles[] = {"one","two","three"};

 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
String item=Titles.get(position);
//another query you can send to the server.
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the "position" is not the item id in the remote database.

Comment: you have to make array of item id on behalf of position you can get which id to be used.